# Android SDK Tools - Installation error

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-manager

I tried to install the Android SDK however I have some problems. I have already downloaded and I have already installed Java JDK and JRE.

I tried to execute this command `sdkmanager --list` but I did not succeed. I´m getting the error:

```
Warning: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found
Warning: Failed to download any source lists!
```

[image: Terminal]

My operating system is Linux Mint, I need help! Thank you!

Comment: Which java version are you using?

Comment: Java version is 9

Comment: Try to downgrade the java version and try once more. Have some random issues with Java v9.

Comment: Works!! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are attempting to connect to a SSL (HTTPS?) address somewhere inside your Java code, that's why it is showing Handshake Exception. 
If not try with path like $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager --list.

Check [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager#usage) link for more info

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem on Ubuntu 18.04.
sdkman solved it:

```sh
sdk install java 9.0.7-zulu
sdk use java 9.0.7-zulu
```

https://sdkman.io/

Answer (score -2):

This isn't an Android question, its related to your operating system and/or SSL settings.